# Jamvm unable to run blocky on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, java, hard-float

I have compiled [jamvm](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jamvm/).I downloaded [blocky](https://github.com/spsn/blocky) for github and extracted it.
Then I followed some instructions [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=22341&start=50) and when I execute it:

```
Error: jamvm VM not supported
```

So I modified ./blocky-jamvm from

```
java -jar -Xmx128M -Djava.library.path=lwjgl/native/linux:/opt/vc/lib -classpath lwjgl/jar/lwjgl.jar:lwjgl/jar/lwjgl_test.jar:lwjgl/jar/lwjgl_util.jar:slick-util.jar:ge-framework.jar:ge-demo.jar ge.demo.game.Blocky $1
```

to

```
jamvm -jar -Xmx128M -Djava.library.path=lwjgl/native/linux:/opt/vc/lib -classpath lwjgl/jar/lwjgl.jar:lwjgl/jar/lwjgl_test.jar:lwjgl/jar/lwjgl_util.jar:slick-util.jar:ge-framework.jar:ge-demo.jar ge.demo.game.Blocky $1
```

Error:

```
Exception occurred while VM initialising.
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Class
```

UPDATE:
I installed gnu classpath and now:

```
(process:1110): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library `lwjgl' not found (as file `liblwjgl.so') in gnu.classpath.boot.library.path and java.library.path
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:763)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:670)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:96)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
   at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
   at ge.framework.render.GLES20Renderer.createDisplay(GLES20Renderer.java:126)
   at ge.demo.game.Blocky.start(Blocky.java:166)
   at ge.demo.game.Blocky.main(Blocky.java:1680)
```

I am running Arch Linux Arm hardfloat. Am I missing something here? Are there differences between the debian `icedtea-7-jre-jamvm` and vanilla `jamvm`?

Comment: I assume one of those paths on your `-classpath` contains the Java API classes? Your exception is saying that they cannot be found. You can try adding the `-xbootclasspath` option to specify where the runtime classes are.

Comment: @Jivings Which ones are the runtime classes?

Comment: `java/lang/Class`, `java/util/List` etc, etc. Usually packaged in `rt.jar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debian icedtea-7-jre-jamvm is designed to be used with OpenJDK.
JamVM is then compiled into a libjvm.so. The JamVM libjvm.so can be used instead of the OpenJDK Hotspot libjvm.so.

"vanilla" jamvm is to be used with gnu classpath
You need to compile and install the **classpath** package if you want to use this combination.

To fix the "Error: jamvm VM not supported"
You need to recompile the Arch Linux java7-openjdk package
and pass --enable-jamvm or --with-additional-vms=jamvm to the IcedTea configure.
This will build jamvm and patch the OpenJDK 7 source code to disable some hotspot specific sun.misc.PerfCounter debug code, this will allow JamVM to be used in combination with OpenJDK 7.

For OpenJDK 6 it is still possible to compile JamVM manually into a libjvm.so and use it without first patching the OpenJDK 6 sourcecode.
build instructions: http://labb.zafena.se/?p=576
The compiled libjvm.so is then placed in
jdk/jre/lib/arm/jamvm/libjvm.so
The file jre/lib/arm/jvm.cfg contains a list of "KNOWN" jvm on your system.
-jamvm KNOWN
must exist inside this list for java -jamvm to operate.